# Extjs 5 ajax PUT and DELETE methods throw 403 errors (csrf token included)

Tags: ajax, django, rest, extjs5, django-csrf

I am building a web application with django-rest-framework and extjs5.
Obviously i faced problems with django's csrf token, which i had to inlude in Extjs's Ajax requests.
But while i implemented POST method successfully, it seems that my implementation doesn't work for PUT and DELETE method.

My POST method code:

```
 onSaveRecordBtnClick: function(){
    Job_Name = this.lookupReference('Job_Name').getValue();     

    var csrf = Ext.util.Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/jobs_api/job/',
        method: "POST",
        params: {
            Job_Name: Job_Name,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
        },
        success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
            var result = MyApp.util.Util.decodeJSON(conn.responseText);
            if (result.success) {
                alert('Job Submission Successfull');
            }
            else {
                MyApp.util.Util.showErrorMsg(conn.responseText);
            }
        },
        failure: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
            MyApp.util.Util.showErrorMsg(conn.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

This works perfectly, but when i try PUT or DELETE method i keep getting:
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:403 FORBIDDEN
{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}

My DELETE method:

```
onJobDblClick : function(grid, record, index, eOpts) {
    var job_id = record.id;
    var csrf = Ext.util.Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    Ext.Ajax.request({
         url: '/jobs_api/job/' + job_id + '/',
         method: "DELETE",
         params: {
            'id': job_id,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
         },
         success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
            var result = MyApp.util.Util.decodeJSON(conn.responseText);
            if (result.success) {
                alert('Job Deleted Successfully');
            }
            else {
                MyApp.util.Util.showErrorMsg(conn.responseText);
            }
        },
        failure: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
            MyApp.util.Util.showErrorMsg(conn.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

My job model is:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Job', {
extend: 'MyApp.model.Base',
fields: [
    { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Job_Name', type: 'string' },
],
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: '/jobs_api/job/',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data'
    }
}
});
```

I don't know why this is happening. Please help!!

Comment: Can you check in your view if CSRF token is passed, and what value it has?

Comment: Nope, when it comes to my view, it wont execute the code inside of my delete function.